Salesforce Rest API Create Lead Including Email Address
Using the rest api I am able to create a lead in salesforce but only when I am not including the email field. When I try to include the email field I get an unknown exception error.
{
    "Email" : "test@gmail.com",
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Doe",
    "LeadSource" : "Website",
    "Company" : "company",
    "Marketing_Campaign__c": "UTM",
    "Last_Page_Shopped__c": "test",
    "Region__c": "EMEA"
}

I have checked all fields and no other is causing this error and I have double checked the documentation and confirmed that the field name is "Email". Any help would be greatly appreciated

Likely because there's automation / custom code on the other side and your payload isn't working with whatever it expects. Login to the org, turn on the debug log and see what's up...or work with org admins if you don't have access.
